# No window-decorations when running Compiz without Sudo

Tags: compiz, xorg

I am running a barebones install of Ubuntu Server 13.04, that I want to boot into a Kiosk like application. For testing, I am launching into X running just XTerm.

When I boot up, if I do `sudo compiz&` in my .xsession, everything comes up fine (my XTerm window has decorations). If I run just `compiz&`, I don't get any decorations (although compiz is listed as a running process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the "sudo" issue there should never be any need to run compiz as root, since you already own the xterm... you are logged in right... lol.
But in some certain circumstances we need to break the rules, like running a gui app as super-user, in these cases sometimes our config files get written to as root, and then whist trying to run that as a normal user we get a borked screen, or bad output from our program. So first off I would check the file perms on you configs for compiz, and the like to be certain that they aren't owned by root now.

Just be advised that gui apps as super-user can be very dangerous, and could potentially bork your entire installation, if not handled with care!!!

As for decorations, try running compiz like this `compiz ccp&`

Comment: File permissions was the correct issue (`~/.config/compiz-1` was set to root). Thanks!